# Use show() to print output

Tags: julia

This question is a follow-up to [this one I asked a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921581/how-to-suppress-function-return). Following the suggestion from that post, I created a custom data type, and also overloaded the `base.show()` function. But the output is not what I expected. So I wonder if I misunderstood something.

```
type Output
    testname::String
    output::Float64
end


function show(io::IO,object::Output)
    println(io,"\tOutput Statistic for $(object.testname)")
    println(io,"$(object.output)")
end
```

I use the following function to illustrate

```
function MEDIAN(x::Array)
    Output("Median: ", median(x))
end

julia> x=randn(10)
julia> MEDIAN(x)
Output("Median: ",0.2267306855631679)
```

I want the output to be the following instead:

```
Median: 0.2267306855631679
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question, you probably forgot to `import Base.show`